# Limit of ratio between iid sums

Tags: probability, limits, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Consider a series of  $n$  i.i.d random variable $X_i, 1\leq i \leq n$
\begin{align*}
X_i = \begin{cases}
       1 &\quad w.p \ \ \ p_1\\
        -1 &\quad w.p \ \ \ 1-p_1\\
     \end{cases}\\
\end{align*}
And another series of  $n$  i.i.d random variable $Y_i$
\begin{align*}
Y_i = \begin{cases}
       1 &\quad w.p \ \ \ p_2\\
        -1 &\quad w.p \ \ \ 1-p_2\\
     \end{cases}\\
\end{align*}

Where $\ 0 < p_1 <p_2 <1/2 \ $. I want to find the following limit:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{Pr(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ge0)}{Pr(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \ge0)}
\end{align*}

I tried using CLT and Lhopital Theorems by assuming that both denominator and numerator are gaussian at the same time and got that the limit is zero. My question is how to do this without this assumption? Alternatively, is there a better way to show the limit is zero?

Answer (score 0):

We don't need (and even, we can NOT) assume that the denominator and numerator follow gaussian distribution simply because the denominator and the numerator receive values only in $[0,1]$.

For the numerator, by applying the CLT, we have:
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i -(2p_1-1)\right)\xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{N}(0,1)\implies \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \overset{\mathcal{D}}{\approx}\mathcal{N}\left(2p_1-1  ,\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

So,

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left( \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \ge 0\right) &\overset{n\to\infty}{=} \mathbb{P}\left( \mathcal{N}\left(2p_1-1  ,\frac{1}{n}\right) \ge 0\right)\\
&\overset{n\to\infty}{\approx}\mathbb{P}\left( \mathcal{N}(0,1) \ge \sqrt{n}(1-2p_1)\right) \\
&\overset{n\to\infty}{\approx} \Phi(\sqrt{n}(2p_1-1)) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
with $\Phi(\cdot)$ the cumulative distribution function of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
For the denumerator, we have the similar result
$$\mathbb{P}\left( \sum_{i=1}^nY_i \ge 0\right) \overset{n\to\infty}{\approx} \Phi(\sqrt{n}(2p_2-1)) \tag{2}$$
From $(1),(2)$ and by applying the L'Hôpital's rule, we have:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\infty}\frac{\mathbb{P}\left( \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \ge 0\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left( \sum_{i=1}^nY_i \ge 0\right)} &= \lim_{n\infty}\frac{\Phi(\sqrt{n}(2p_1-1)) }{\Phi(\sqrt{n}(2p_2-1)) } \\
&\overset{\text{l'hopital}}{=} \lim_{n\infty}\frac{\phi(\sqrt{n}(2p_1-1)) }{\phi(\sqrt{n}(2p_2-1)) }\\
&= \lim_{n\infty}\frac{\exp{\left(-\frac{n(2p_1-1)^2}{2}\right)}/(2\pi)}{\exp{\left(-\frac{n(2p_2-1)^2}{2}\right)}/(2\pi)}\\
&=\lim_{n\infty} \exp{\left(-\frac{n}{2}\left((2p_1-1)^2 -(2p_2-1)^2 \right)\right)}\\
&=\lim_{n\infty} \exp{\left(2n(p_2-p_1)(p_1+p_2-1)\right)}\\
&\color{red}{=0}
\end{align}$$

The last equality is because $0<p_1<p_2 <1/2$.